# how to debug ListView Code when programming android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, android-2.2-froyo

as the following picture shows, the source of ListView is not included by the sdk, so how to get the source for this class?

then i may debug into the code of Listview.

[image]

**Edit1**:  i am using sdk 2.2, it don't have a module named source code, only android 4.x have such module:(

[image]

[image]

Comment: where are the pictures??

Comment: @RKN refresh your browser, and you will see it:)

Comment: you may need to download code from AOSP site http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: @nandeesh i don't need to build Rom, and don't need to build CM, why i should download all the android source code? all i need is some kind of framework...

Comment: yeah, but you need the code to debug. if you want to just reference it , you can check here http://androidxref.com/. If you donwload , create a another project with this code in eclipse and you can debug even in ListView

Answer (score 1):

Type `android` into your console to open the Android SDK Manager. Expand the Android version you would like to use, mark the *Sources for Android SDK* checkbox and hit *Install*. That's everything, you need to do. You will find the sources afterwards in `<SDK_PATH>/sources/android-XX`. You IDE should now be able to debug into the code (at least NetBeans does).

**Edit (for 2.2)**

I guess if you really want the sources for 2.2, you will need to [checkout the whole android project](http://source.android.com/source/index.html) and switch to the required tag. (Get a list of all tags with `git tag -l`) You could copy that code to the above mentioned folder, and see if your IDE detects it there.

Comment: yes, but i think android code is managed by repo, not git, so can i download only part of android code rather than the whole android project?